# When do I pronounce a non-existent “r” between adjacent vowel sounds?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, intrusive-r

If I say two words consecutively, with the first ending in a vowel sound and the second starting with one, when is it correct to include a non-existent *r* between those two words?

Examples from phrases I've heard:

> - I saw (r)a movie
> - They saw (r)us
> - Law (r)and order
> - That's the idea, (r)anyway.

I heard the last one in the movie *Edge of Tomorrow* yesterday.

Is this grammatically correct? If so, is the omission of the *r* grammatically incorrect? Are there any rules regarding this?

Comment: I believe the phantom 'r' you're hearing is entirely an artifact of regional accent. I live in New Hampshire, and tend to hear a lot of the older folks here include it. In the younger generation, the accent has shifted more towards General American, and the 'r' isn't included. (We've been known to make fun of people who say "sawr" and "lawr" instead of "saw" and "law").

Comment: The funny thing is that speakers with this accent don't just insert 'r's, they elide them elsewhere! For example, "I saw a car" might be pronounced "I sawr a cah".

Comment: This has nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: FWIW, it (almost?) never shows up in Canadian English.

Comment: @Gabe as we say in Boston - "Where we never pronounce the letter 'r' unless we have a good idear."

Comment: FWIW, Other than "idear," I've never heard of the other ones you mention.

Comment: The character **Hagrid** from the *Harry Potter* series is a good example of the usage. As others have said, it's not a grammar nor phonetics issue, it's purely accentual.

Comment: Obviously, you don't HAVE to use it. Having said that... As far as I know, it's just a way people speak at times, and it's part of the RP standard. The "r" seems to have the same function as the "n" in "an" (eg. an apple) or the glide in "The ZOO is" [the zoowiz]. However, as a non-native speaker, I don't use it myself, and to my ear it sounds half old-fashioned, half jocular. hth.

Comment: The only occasion I've encountered where one *has* to use it is in the joke, "What do you call a one-eyed dinosaur?" "A doyouthinkhesaurus".

Comment: I once heard of a professor of English calling a Shakespearean play "Orthello".  When I hear an "r" in "the idea is", pronounced as "the idearis", or other instances of this intrusive "r", it's as if you stabbed me with a pin at that moment: it distracts from what is being said.

Comment: My mother swears that she saw a advertising sign in a Portland, Maine department store in the early '60s: "Pahkers on Sale" [Parkas on Sale].

Comment: It's an intrusive-r in some non-rhotic dialects. It is not part of standard English (British or American or otherwise). If you want to sound more accurately like one of these non-rhotic dialects, then you would use it. If you want to speak standard English then you should not use it.

Comment: As for why it's included in those phrases, I'll take your first example: “I saw a movie”. In non-rhotic accents, “saw” is homophonous with “soar” - /sɔː/, with the “dawn” vowel. The ‘r’ isn't pronounced because it's in the syllable coda. But when ‘r’ can become part of an onset, as in “We soar over the fields”, it sometimes is pronounced (“soar over” -> /sɔːɹˈəʊvə/). Hence, non-rhotic speakers sometimes get into the habit of using /ɹ/ as a buffer consonant between a long vowel and another vowel, because the long vowel sounds as if it was followed by a silent ‘r’. Hence /sɔː ə/ -> /sɔːɹə/.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I support [Dan Rumney's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/177497/37177) and I would like to explain a bit more.

In **non-rhotic** English accents —ones in which an 'R' sound is not pronounced if it occurs before a consonant or "prosodic break"— an R at the end of a word would not normally be pronounced, unless it was followed by a word starting with a vowel, for example in the expression "tuner amp". This is a **linking R**. Most English accents in England (including Received Pronunciation), Wales and the Southern Hemisphere are **non-rhotic**.

These accents also tend to insert an R in the same cases as above, for words ending with a vowel sound, *even if an R is not written there*, in order to avoid hiatus between the two vowel sounds. For example, in the phrase "bacteria in it", an unwritten R might be pronounced between "bacteria" and "in". This is an **intrusive R**. In your examples this happens even though "saw" ends in a 'W', because when spoken it ends with a /ɔː/ vowel sound, and is then followed by another vowel sound.

For a **rhotic** accent, there is no "Linking R" —the 'R' in those cases is already pronounced anyway— and a hiatus is preferred between two vowel sounds, instead of an intrusive R. Most English accents spoken in North America (including General American), Scotland and Ireland are **rhotic**.

To summarise when you *may* pronounce an **Intrusive R**:

> **If you are speaking in a non-rhotic accent *and* there are two subsequent vowel sounds with no "prosodic break" then you may wish to use the Intrusive R between them, to avoid hiatus.**

The Wikipedia article about [Linking & Intrusive R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R#Intrusive_R) provides more examples and details about where and when these tend to be used. You might also be interested in the article about [rhotic and non-rhotic accents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents).

Comment: +1. An answer to this question is simply not complete without discussing rhotic and non-rhotic accents. Some of the other answers make it sound like non-rhotic accents are rare, regional things, but in most English-speaking countries non-rhotic accent are more common than rhotic ones.

Comment: Thanks for summing up the differences between rhotic and non-rhotic accents. The links you provided were helpful for follow-up.

Comment: Hmmm, nicely written and mostly correct, but I'd guarantee that you wouldn't use an intrusive R in the sequence *blue eyes* or in the sequence *the end*. This is because we only use intrusive R after a non-high vowel. [i.e. one that doesn't end a) in  an /u:/ or  a diphthong ending in ʊ - for which we can use a mini w instead  or b) end in an /i:/ or a diphthong ending in ɪ, for which we'd use a j instead].

Answer (score 43):

**Never!**

It's called "the lazy 'R'", and to my Scottish ear it sounds terrible. However, some would say it's a matter of accent or dialect.

If you are learning English as second language, then you shouldn't use it at all.

It's not grammar, though, it's pronunciation.

Comment: Whether it sounds terrible or not is a matter of opinion, but this answer is definitely correct in that it's a feature of how some accents work rather than standard English. Many people who would speak with it would strive to omit it if they were taking pains to "speak properly".

Comment: Seriously... never. It sounds ridiculous.

Comment: There are a number of accents of English where this is standard, and if you speak one of these already, I don't think there's any reason to try to eliminate the linking 'R'. But if you're learning English as a second language, then unless you want to sound like a native speaker from Southern England, a native New Yorker, or any of the other accents that do this, there is no reason to try to do this. (And why on Earth would one want to speak like a native New Yorker or Bostonian unless one were an actor?)

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks for specifying the accents this is common to. It was useful. I'm from India, and I've never heard anyone use the lazy R except at the movies. But I do remember an English teacher in the sixth-grade telling me that this was the correct way to speak. Hence, the curiosity. Good thing I didn't listen to him.

Comment: You never have to use it, but you should be able to understand it when someone else uses it.

Comment: Having lived in New Zealand for a time, I can attest that it is incredibly common in the New Zealand accent and Australian accent.

Comment: A nation which says "Scortish" has no standing to complain about a lazy R.

Comment: @Ben What nation is that? I've never heard anyone say that.

Comment: But if there's a pattern to when people do this, wouldn't that make it a matter of grammar as well?

Comment: The first word in this answer seems like it’s supposed to answer the question pithily—but it doesn’t. The question does ask any questions that can meaningfully be answered with the word ‘never’. Are you saying you never have to use an intrusive r? Or that you should never use it? @ChristoferOhlsson No. Grammar is not just anything that can be described by patterns.

Comment: For what it's worth -- and this has been fairly thoroughly discussed already -- the original question was "When do I pronounce a non-existent “r” between adjacent vowel sounds?" Which I interpreted as "When _should_ I...?" I went on to explain why to my mind you never "should" do it, and how it always sounds wrong. Others disagree.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion The answer is that *if* your English is rhotic (which yours is), you shouldn't use an intrustive /r/. But if your English is non-rhotic, then you may want to, and it will sound perfectly normal.

Answer (score 35):

Martin (and commenters) are over-stating their position a bit.

It's true that you never *have* to insert the R, but the idea that it's incorrect pronunciation stems from the idea that some English speaking accents are more correct than others. This is, of course, ridiculous.

It may be worth noting that [John C Wells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Wells) considered the intrusive R to be part of Received Pronunciation. However, since the minority of native English speakers speak with an RP accent, it doesn't really matter.

So, is it necessary to use the intrusive R? Only if you're learning English in an accent that uses it. If you're learning a rhotic dialect, then the intrusive R would definitely be out of place.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I agree with you that dialect snobbery is ridiculous. Especially on a site like this.

The takeaway for me here is that this is a dialect issue, not a grammar/pronunciation one, and hence I'm doing nothing wrong in not uttering the 'r'.

Comment: I didn't actually say it was _wrong_; just that it grates on me.

Comment: There are plenty of rhotic dialects where intrusive r is common enough. In particular, the phrase “the idea is”, in my experience, nearly always gets an intrusive r in General American, even if “I saw a movie” doesn’t.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking purely from experience and not really having much technical knowledge on the subject, I'd say it's necessary in some accents. I'm Australian, but I don't have a very strong Aussie accent, closer to British. When I say something like "I saw a train", I pronounce it as "I saw ra train". Likewise, when I say "sawing", I pronounce it "sawring". If I try saying it without the 'R' sound, I sound like I have a speech impediment (like Barry Kripke from Big Bang or Jonathan Ross).

There is no one correct answer for this question. In this case, I would say the joining 'R' sound is necessary. However, it probably sounds awful in some American accents, for example, or in the Scottish accent, as Martin says.

Answer (score 0):

British English developed a number of regional accents, in part from the history of who lived there originally, and what invaders conquered that area. You have the original Celtic influences in Scotland, Ireland, Wales, and Cornwall; Norse in much of eastern England; traces of Anglo-Saxon (Germanic) in the southeast, etc.

In the US, New England (Boston, Maine/DownEast accents in particular) was originally settled by people from Anglica, in eastern England. They tend to strongly exhibit the "R" behaviors discussed in this thread. In the Mid-Atlantic region, most of the early settlers were from Cornwall, Devon, and other southern areas, and they speak differently (not exhibiting the discussed "R" behaviors). This is the accent which has spread throughout much of the US as the "standard American" accent or pronunciation.

There are, of course, many other immigrant influences on US regional pronunciations (Dutch, Italian and Yiddish in the New York City area; French in northern New England and Louisiana; Swedish and Norwegian in the upper Midwest; German in Wisconsin and Pennsylvania; Spanish in the southwest). With widespread use of TV, radio, and sound recordings, the regional differences are dying out, replaced with a more uniform sound.

Answer (score -2):

Truthfully, it's not hard to pronounce subsequent vowels with an "R". Just because a British person uses the consonant doesn't mean another should have to in order to feel or be "normal". Americans each different--and so do the British.  I personally believe that if you use a "throaty T", then you can easily pronounce subsequent vowels without "intrusive R's".
Simply saying "I'm British/Australian, so I must use the 'intrusive R' in order to not sound dumb!" simply does not suffice. It neither means you have sub-par intelligence nor and impediment.

Answer (score -3):

Some people drop the "r" sound, then feel the need to make up for it by inserting a phantom "r" where none exists, a form of hypercorrection.  Bostonians can famously pahk their cahs at Hahvahd Yahd, then have the lawng ahm of the lawr  reach out and write them tickets.

Comment: Although I think this answer is somewhat relevant, it's not applicable in this case; **intrusive R** is not a hypercorrection, but rather a feature of **non-rhotic** accents, used to avoid hiatus between subsequent vowels. However, a related hypercorrection exists: [H-adding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection#H-adding). This is when superfluous 'H's are prepended to words in contrast with accents where H-dropping occurs.