# Explanation and rules for adding and subtracting 'r's in British pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, linguistics

For example, the sentence, "The Premier of China drank vodka and beer in his car with Obama." A BBC presenter would pronounce it like:

*The **Premieh** of **Chiner** drank **vodker** and **bee'h** in his **ca'** with **Obam-er**.*

In other words, they add 'r's where they don't belong and eliminate them where they do.

Is there any linguistic explanation for how this evolved? Are there any formal rules regarding this?

Comment: You should use IPA (phonetic alphabet) to illustrate correctly what you mean. Try using this tool http://upodn.com/. And provide some sort of evidence, e.g. BBC website, to back up your claim. I could post an answer saying you're wrong, adding that it's not true British speakers add -r onto China. Personally, I think you are mixing the -r sound with the  [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) one.

Comment: Hi, Matt. I really liked your question you posted yesterday. The problem is "Why is it?" type of question doesn't work very well here because it could be too broad or generate only primarily-opinion-based answers. Please edit your question focusing on English Language and its Usage. BTW, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: there are sooo many regional differences in pronunciation, in particular with "r", in all English-speaking countries (as well many as other languages, which I find interesting), that there really is no single, simple, meaningful response to this question, other than perhaps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English

Comment: Thank you Mari-Lou A and Rathony. Your critiques have been well received, and the post has been modified. Much appreciated.

Comment: @michael_n. That is interesting and seems to answer the question perfectly. I never heard of rhoticity before.

Comment: ...I guess I can add it as an answer....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I pronounce a non-existent “r” between adjacent vowel sounds?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177430/when-do-i-pronounce-a-non-existent-r-between-adjacent-vowel-sounds)

Comment: Matt, where did you get your sentence from? Which BBC presenter? (the placement of where the r's are pronounced doesn't seem right to me for RP).

Comment: @Mari-LouA We might use an intrusive /r/ after *China* if the following word begins with a vowel sound :)

Comment: @Araucaria I have no idea about that, I know next to nothing about the "rules" or "hows" of pronunciation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In case it helps with your teaching: if words end with an ɪ or  i: sound then we can use a mini j  to separate the word from a following vowel (the sound j is very similar to the vowels ɪ and i:). If the word ends in a ʊ or u: sound we can use a mini w (w is a similar to the vowels  ʊ and u:). If the word ends in *any* other vowel, we can use an /r/. If there's a mini j or w, it won't have the full length of a real /j/ or /w/. However, if we use an /r/ it *will* behave exactly like a real /r/ including having the length of a full consonant.

Comment: @PeterShor Maybe kinda, but there's also just the question of when non-rhotic speakers pronounce orthographic R in the first place. Also, unfortunately, none of the answers over there is fully correct :( Apart from Dancrumbs, but his doesn't actually explain when to use intrusive /r/.

Comment: @PeterShor sinisterstuf's answer is mostly on the ball (and well-written), but it would give you the impression that we could use an intrusive /r/ in the sequence *blue eyes*, for example, which we can't.

Comment: Yes ... in *blue eyes* you insert a /w/ and not an /r/.

Comment: It should be noted here that there's no such thing as "British pronunciation". There is more variation in the pronunciation of the English language within Britain than there is in the rest of the English-speaking world. You have to say which of the very many British dialects of English you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, Mike, you're absolutely right. But that list would be very long indeed! I think there's a character limit on titles.

Comment: @Matt The question would be no longer if it replaced "British pronunciation" with "Wigan accent" or "Estuary English" or whatever pronunciation you're talking about.

Answer (score 18):

Rhotic English is a term to describes varieties of English in which orthographic R is usually pronounced, even at the end of a syllable. In non-rhotic varieties of English - such as Southern Standard British English - orthographic R is only pronounced if followed by a vowel. It doesn't matter if there is a double R or not in the orthography:

- car / ka:
- car park / ka: pa:k
- car alarm / ka:r əla:m
- carrot / kærət

Modern SSBE also allows intrusive /r/. We sometimes use this when a word ending in a non-high vowel sound is followed by a word beginning with another vowel. The /r/ has the function of separating the two vowel sounds:

- Pippa Andrews / pɪpər ændru:z

**The Original Poster's example**

> The Premie**r** of China drank vodka and bee**r** in his car with Obama.

In terms of syllable-final orthographic Rs, there are two followed by vowel sounds, the ones at the ends of the words *Premier* and *beer*. These will be pronounced in SSBE. There is also one instance of a word ending in a (non-high) vowel being followed by another vowel sound. This is in the sequence *vodka and*. We may see speakers using an intrusive /r/ between *vodka* and *and*:

> ðə premiə**r** əv tʃaɪnə dræŋk vɒdkə**r** ən bɪə**r** ɪn ɪz kɑ: wɪð əbɑ:mə

Comment: +1 With this post, marathon viewing of old Monty Pythons, and some practice, I bet anyone could fake a British accent well enough to fool 95% of Americans.

Comment: Is linking r always used, or is it sometimes not? I ask because in the similar French phenomenon of *liaison,* there are some contexts where (stigmatized) intrusive consonants can occur, but there are also many contexts where using a linking consonant is optional. I wondered if British "linking r" might only occur part of the time, depending on factors like speed, formality, speaker age and the like.

Comment: @sumelic It is very variable. Some speakers may frequently include an intrusive r in normal conversation, then omit it when repeating a phrase slowly for emphasis.

Comment: Very good, but "car alarm" is pronounced /ka: rəla:m/ or "ca ralarm" where the "r" ends up at the start of "alarm" instead of the end of "car".

Comment: @CJDennis I agree, I think (although it's very difficult to say this with any authority even from a waveform for example - ones theoretical background will come into play). However, the convention is always to put the /r/ with the preceding word. The real fact is that the white space in transcription doesn't really count for very much. In connected speech allthewordstendtojustrunintoeachother! :-)

Comment: @sumelic Within words  linking /r/ is mandatory after vowels (e.g. *score* versus *scoring*). Across word boundaries, it is somewhat variable. In my experience of transcribing actual speech, it does occur the vast majority of the time for modern SSBE. Intrusive /r/ however, is very variable indeed both word internally (*draw* versus *drawing*) and across word boundaries. The term /r/-liaison is also used in English for both linking and intrusive /r/. Historically, prescriptivists have tried to paint intrusive-/r/ (as opposed to linking-/r/) as 'substandard'. This view is rare nowadays

Answer (score 7):

Whether or not 'r' sounds that don't precede a vowel are pronounced is called 'rhoticity'.  Some dialects (Most of those from England, Australia, and New Zealand for instance) are non-rhotic and only pronounce 'r' before a vowel.  Dialects from Scotland, Ireland, and North America are mostly rhotic and pronounce 'r' whether or not it precedes a vowel.  Non-rhotic speakers do change the preceding vowel, usually by lengthening it or combining it with schwa (an 'eh' sound) to form a dipthong.

The 'followed by a vowel' rule can include the next word starting with a vowel: this is called a 'linking r'.  Less frequently there is also an 'intrusive r' which is added between vowels that would otherwise blur together.  When intrusive r is not used, a glottal stop is used (as in most North American dialects).  Whether an intrusive r or glottal stop is used, it's generally not noticed by the speaker or by any speakers who are used to it.

In some British dialects 'a' can also be pronounced in a way that sounds to those unfamiliar with it somewhat like 'ar' when it's at the end of a syllable.  There isn't really an 'r', just a vowel you're not used to.

In your example, "premier", "beer", and "car" all get affected by non-rhoticity,  "China" and "Obama" are probably examples of unfamiliar vowels that you are mishearing as ending with 'r', and "vodka and" is an example of an intrusive r.

Answer (score 2):

There are many regional differences in pronunciation, in particular with "r", for speakers of English (as well many as other languages), that there really is no simple answer, other than perhaps [Rhoticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English) :

> "Rhoticity in English refers to the situations in which English speakers pronounce the historical rhotic consonant /r/, and is one of the most prominent distinctions by which English varieties can be classified."