# The /r/ sound in "drawing" in British English?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

One of my pet peeves is that, in the UK, many people seem to mispronounce the word "drawing".  The correct pronouciation is [**/ˈdrɔː.ɪŋ/**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/drawing). Why then, do so many people allow that /r/ to creep in to give **/ˈdrɔː.rɪŋ/**?

This is particularly annoying when educated and otherwise erudite people make this mistake.

Can anyone shed any light as to the cause or explanation for this?

Comment: Seems other Saffa's also recoil at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JscFw5mVSvY

Comment: Because many people from the U.K. are unable to pronounce two vowels in a row without putting a consonant in between them.

Comment: Because (in this particular case) people can't remember whether to use *draw* or *drawer* as they are invariably (and erroneously) pronounced identically, so put the extra 'r' in the gerund just in case.

Comment: This is not just a British thing.  This is a common accent from the Boston Mass area in the US, as exemplified by Norm Abrams on *The Old Yankee Workshop* TV show.  Oddly, this is usually paired with the dropping of the "R" sound in other words -- a "non-rhotic" dialect.

Comment: (Pretty sure there are a half-dozen good dupes to reference, if you look for them.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: But do people from the U.S. Northeast with non-rhotic dialects say *drawring*? They certainly say *I sawr him*, *the idear of*, *lawr and order* and *Brender and Eddie.* But do they stick /r/s in the ***middle*** of words like *drawring*?

Comment: @Brad What's a 'Saffa'?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R TL;DR - in some non-rhotic dialects there is a vestige of the 'r' which because it is preserved if the following word has a vowel, it is added where it never was between two vowels.

Comment: @PeterShor - If you say "measured drawering" to someone of a certain age and economic class in the US they will instantly associate it with Norm.

Comment: @Mitch Saffa=South African.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I pronounce a non-existent “r” between adjacent vowel sounds?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177430/when-do-i-pronounce-a-non-existent-r-between-adjacent-vowel-sounds), another relevant question is [Explanation and rules for adding and subtracting 'r's in British pronunciation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298856/explanation-and-rules-for-adding-and-subtracting-rs-in-british-pronunciation?lq=1)