# How is the word "saw" pronounced in the US, specifically, New York?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

English is my second language, therefore I have trouble grasping certain words phonetically.

When I speak with my co-workers, sometimes and almost always, they pronounce the word *saw*  as *sawr*, like,  "I sawr this movie last night", and I can distinctly tell that there is an "R" sound at the end of the word *saw*.

Now I pronounce the word *saw* as in a saw with which you cut wood. I wouldn't say "Hey Mike, hand me that sawr so I can cut this wood", although this would be a better word to be used as there is cutting involved.

This has me confused, do I say "I sawr her" or "I saw her"? Can someone please clarify?

Comment: I have lived my whole life in NYC. I was born and raised (and currently reside) in Manhattan. Most people say "saw", but some people say "sawr", often those from adjoining NJ.

Comment: 'saw' is standard English. If you try to say 'sawr' it will sound very dialectal and non-standard. You want to say 'saw' unless you're very embedded in a particular community that distinctly says 'sawr' (that's general advice for learning any language).

Comment: @Dan: having lived in New Jersey for nearly two decades, I don't think any more people in New Jersey say *sawr* than people in Brooklyn or Queens. People who live in Manhattan tend to have a lot more money, and better-off people are more likely to speak standard English.

Comment: Why is that? Why do rich folks speak properly and not in some rich slang which the peasants won't understand?

Comment: @Zohaib: because they interact with other rich folk, who also speak properly. I think this is because rich folk move around a lot nowadays, so they tend to lose regional accents.

Comment: @PeterShor that makes a lot more sense. Also that they study abroad so they have to keep some sort of a standard english and also when reading books you can't really read it in the author's accent.

Comment: In contemporary times, "rich people"'s language is more standardized because their education is more consistent. In the middle ages, there was a phenomenon where the middle class adjusted their language to emulate how they believed rich people (then, the aristrocracy) spoke, but they got it all wrong, and actually set themselves further apart.

Comment: May be useful: [ELI5: How did the British pronunciation of "saw" become "sawr"?](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1sigmk/eli5_how_did_the_british_pronunciation_of_saw/)

Comment: @Dan: It used to be that there was an upper-class Boston accent – listen to JFK's speeches – and a lower-class Boston accent. I'm sure this was true other places in the country, as well. Nowadays, while the lower-class Boston accent is a little rarer, the upper-class Boston accent may have disappeared entirely.

Comment: Related: [When do I pronounce a non-existent “r” between adjacent vowel sounds?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/177430/50044)

Comment: @Zohaib "Why do rich folks speak properly and not in some rich slang which the peasants won't understand?" in the US nowadays, most people speak standard GenAmE. Before universal education and media, it would not be wrong to call a the rich speech a slang for that narrow set. 'Proper' is simply a social value, both dialects would be consistent with themselves.

Comment: The use of the "non-existent" "r" sound in words like "saw" is a characteristic of several "non-rhotic" dialects (dialects that, curiously, drop the "r" sound from other words).  These dialects occur in parts of the British Isles and in parts of New York City and, I'm thinking, Ohio and Michigan (but I may misremember).  It is not standard English, and you should avoid the practice unless your intent is to mimic one of these dialects.

Answer (score 4):

The people from New York who say *sawr* only say it if the following word starts with a vowel or is *him, his, her* (in which case the 'h' gets dropped). As far as I know, nobody says *"I sawr this movie last night,"* alhough they would say *"I sawr a movie last night."*

Comment: Does the same follow for "wartch" (as in "wristwatch")? The people I know who say "sawr" also say "wartch", but I haven't paid attention to the phonetic context.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say "wartch"

Comment: @Peter Shor Aha that makes sense. They just drop the H.

Comment: @Dan: *wartch* is really strange.

Comment: Maybe it's a Pennsyltucky thing.  I'm googling to see if anyone has studied it.

Comment: @Dan: *warsh* is common throughout the Midwest, and I've heard *gararge* from Midwesterners as well. So maybe *wartch* is part of the same phenomenon (which I read originally comes from Ireland).

Comment: @PeterShor yes the Irish are rather heavy on their "R" sounds.

Comment: I have heard "wartch" on rare occasions.